# Does Office 365 work properly on Ubuntu & Chrome OS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, microsoft-office, google-chrome-os

And so maybe I can finally get rid of Windows in our office.

Comment: You are running an office on Chrome OS? :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the webmail portion of Office 365, then it doesn't work on Linux + Chrome, but as far as I can tell, there is no reason it shouldn't work.

I think the issue is just with the Linux + Chrome user agent. The webmail works fine under Chrome on Windows and Os X, so I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be able to work fine under Linux. Microsoft most likely "forgot" to include the user agent for the Linux + Chrome combo.

**Update:**
Got this working on Linux using this user agent spoofer extension, http://spoofer-extension.appspot.com/.

It doesn't work on the built in Windows Chrome 13 user agent, but if you use this user agent , [taken from this site](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/),    `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7` It should work.

Note that you may have to logout and log back in for the user agent to be properly reread.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the answer is no. Here are the system requirements:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/system-requirements.aspx#fbid=DEOG7U8bNvf

Comment: There's this page, which seems to contradict it:http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/office365-enterprises/ff652534.aspx

Comment: @chrism2671 You asked about the whole thing, and the system requirements were clear. Of course, all the contradictions relate to the ability to run web-based apps only. Of course, any computer with most browsers can do that.

Comment: OK I've tried this out now. The 'office' (word, excel) part of Office 365 does indeed work; however it is an implementation that is closer to google docs than it is to office feature wise- hardly 'Microsoft Office' running on linux. Still just a pipe dream...

Comment: @chrism2671 Thank you for the update. To be honest, that is what I was thinking was going to be the case, but I was not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried seeing if I could edit a word document in Chrome (from Ubuntu precise). I installed the moonlight chrome extension, as suggested. It loaded my document fine, but after trying a single edit, I ended up with a error and was unable to proceed. So, based on this experience, it doesn't work, and we will have to travel the virtualbox route.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

Microsoft Office 365 for Business includes several features. As Chrome OS is primarily a web-based operating system, and Office 365 has web-based features, you can run Office 365 on a Chromebook.

For email, contacts & calendar - you've got Exchange Online.
For file storage - you've got OneDrive for Business.
For Word, Excel, PowerPoint, OneNote - you've got the online office suite.

Everything has been proven to run fine on Chrome, and Chrome OS. It will only ever replace Windows in the business environment if you don't have a need for Windows in the business environment.

I'm sure if you provided more detail as to your requirements we could suggest a better solution.

Comment: Is your answer based on real experience or you just think, it shall work?

Answer (score 0):

The webapp part of it [SHOULD](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/office-professional-plus.aspx#fbid=zPtC5I779u3) in theory. However, the performance and specifics may depend - they may have a mobile device optimised layout.