# Using Office 365 for work collaboration on a Chromebook

Tags: office365, onedrive, chromebook

Has anyone tried using Office 365 (Outlook, Word, Excel, Ppt) on a Chromebook?

I do not own a Chromebook. This [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-install-and-run-microsoft-office-on-a-chromebook-32f14a23-2c1a-4579-b973-d4b1d78561ad) shows that I can install and run Office mobile app on a Chromebook. However, OneDrive support is not available.

Here is my guess of a workaround. From Chrome browser, I can download a file from OneDrive to local drive. Then I can edit the file using Office mobile app. Then I can upload the changed file back to OneDrive. This should be doable but very inconvenient.

Or I can just open a file in OneDrve inside the Chrome browser and view/edit with "Office for web". "Office for web" is not a full office so its features are limited.

A similar question was asked eight years ago. [Does Office 365 work properly on Ubuntu & Chrome OS?](https://superuser.com/questions/303929/does-office-365-work-properly-on-ubuntu-chrome-os/742410#742410).

I hope the situation has changed.

Comment: For more collaboration scenarios, read [Collaborate from anywhere using Microsoft 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/collaborate-from-anywhere-using-microsoft-365-ac05a41e-0b49-4420-9ebc-190ee4e744f4?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) and [Collaborate with Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/collaborate-with-office-0613cf58-e8e2-48bc-a358-c4ec38d14950). Since there isn't available Office 365 desktop clients on Chromebook and better collaboration experience is based on Office 365 desktop clients, it's recommend to enjoy Office 365 co-authoring with Office for web on web browser.

Comment: @HerbGu_MSFT Thanks for the response. I agree with you. The only way to find out is for me to get a Chromebook and try it out.

Comment: Office is still really a desktop app with a lesser version on the web.  You don't really need to get a Chromebook to try the web version though.  Just log in on Chrome on your existing computer.   Google Docs on the other hand is a web app first and foremost so consider it instead.  The word processor part is just OK but the spreadsheet part is quite good.